# how to change the look of a paragraph in a php file

Tags: php, css

I've tried to make the file a html file, or just put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">` in immediately but it just doesn't work.
I'd like to be able the change the pharagraph *producten* font size.

this is my code so far (its about the last part ())

```
<?php
  include('DatabaseConnector.php');
  $database = new DatabaseConnector("test", "root", "");
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

    $email = $database->selectValue("SELECT emailadres FROM klant WHERE naam = 'Bibiche' AND achternaam = 'Laarakkers'");
      echo "Het emailadres van Bibiche Laarakkers is $email.";

    $productInfo = $database->selectSingleRow("SELECT gewicht, prijs, calorieen FROM product WHERE naam = 'Sausage Muffin with Egg Whites'");
      echo "<h2> Sausage Muffin with Egg Whites </h2>";
      echo "<p>Gewicht: " . $productInfo['gewicht'] . "<br>";
      echo "Prijs: " . $productInfo['prijs'] . "<br>";
      echo "Aantal Calorieën: " . $productInfo['calorieen'] . "</p>";

      $producten = $database->selectRows("SELECT naam, prijs FROM product");
          foreach($producten as $product) {
            echo "<p class='pruducten'> Product:" . $product['naam'] . "<br>";
          echo "Prijs:" . $product['prijs'] . "</p>";

          }
?>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to output a complete document? If so remember to start by echoing e.g. <!doctype html> <html> <head> <title>   </title> your link element here </head> <body>rest of your code </body></html> That is, put that link into the head of your document.

Comment: _"or just put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">` in immediately but it just doesn't work"_ - of course that doesn't work, you can not just write HTML code into PHP code directly like that. But you can see how that was handled for the `h2` or `p` elements, right? And https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php can also be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to print the link in php code, could you try something like this and see if it works?

The reason I use echo is so that it will print out the code of the stylesheet. If I place the code directly into the middle of php without echoing it or wrapping it in '' it will not show up or print out correctly.

```
<?php
  include('DatabaseConnector.php');
  $database = new DatabaseConnector("test", "root", "");
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">';

    $email = $database->selectValue("SELECT emailadres FROM klant WHERE naam = 'Bibiche' AND achternaam = 'Laarakkers'");
      echo "Het emailadres van Bibiche Laarakkers is $email.";

    $productInfo = $database->selectSingleRow("SELECT gewicht, prijs, calorieen FROM product WHERE naam = 'Sausage Muffin with Egg Whites'");
      echo "<h2> Sausage Muffin with Egg Whites </h2>";
      echo "<p>Gewicht: " . $productInfo['gewicht'] . "<br>";
      echo "Prijs: " . $productInfo['prijs'] . "<br>";
      echo "Aantal Calorieën: " . $productInfo['calorieen'] . "</p>";

      $producten = $database->selectRows("SELECT naam, prijs FROM product");
          foreach($producten as $product) {
            echo "<p class='pruducten'> Product:" . $product['naam'] . "<br>";
          echo "Prijs:" . $product['prijs'] . "</p>";

          }
?>
```

If that doesn't work since css links are best used in the < head > section of documents, you could print out the code directly into it by echoing the code so it properly prints it onto the page. Like this:

```
<?php
  include('DatabaseConnector.php');
  $database = new DatabaseConnector("test", "root", "");
  echo '<style type="text/css">
    .pruducten {
        font-size:1rem;
    }
    </style>';
    $email = $database->selectValue("SELECT emailadres FROM klant WHERE naam = 'Bibiche' AND achternaam = 'Laarakkers'");
      echo "Het emailadres van Bibiche Laarakkers is $email.";

    $productInfo = $database->selectSingleRow("SELECT gewicht, prijs, calorieen FROM product WHERE naam = 'Sausage Muffin with Egg Whites'");
      echo "<h2> Sausage Muffin with Egg Whites </h2>";
      echo "<p>Gewicht: " . $productInfo['gewicht'] . "<br>";
      echo "Prijs: " . $productInfo['prijs'] . "<br>";
      echo "Aantal Calorieën: " . $productInfo['calorieen'] . "</p>";

      $producten = $database->selectRows("SELECT naam, prijs FROM product");
          foreach($producten as $product) {
            echo "<p class='pruducten'> Product:" . $product['naam'] . "<br>";
          echo "Prijs:" . $product['prijs'] . "</p>";

          }
?>
```

The above would be my approach if you absolutely had to have every aspect of the page printed all in php code.

There are other ways of doing this by using html directly in a php file such as making sure it has a < head > section and more. But I wanted to work on the path you were taking to better assist you with your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).